# How do I subset a data.table based on another data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to get my head around how to use data.tables. It is not going well.

I have a large data.table with a bunch of returns and AUM. I subsetted that data.table into two data.tables, one with returns, and one with AUM. I now want to subset the returns data.table, to get only the returns from funds with AUM less than the 50th percentile.

To give you an idea, this is my code:

```
fundDetails <- data.table(read.table("Fund_Deets.csv", sep = ",", fill = TRUE, quote="\"", header=TRUE))
fundNAV <- data.table(read.table("NAV_AUM.csv", sep = ",", fill = TRUE, quote="\"", header=TRUE))

allFundDetails <- fundDetails[Currency == 'USD']
allFundNAV <- fundNAV[Fund.ID %in% allFundDetails$Fund.ID]
allFundAUM <- allFundNAV[Type == 'AUM', -c(1,3), with = FALSE]
allFundAUM <- setnames(data.table(t(sapply(allFundAUM[,-1, with = FALSE],as.numeric))), as.character(allFundAUM$Fund.ID))
allFundReturns <- allFundNAV[Type == 'Return', -c(1,3), with = FALSE]
allFundReturns <- setnames(data.table(t(sapply(allFundReturns[,-1, with = FALSE],as.numeric)/100)), as.character(allFundReturns$Fund.ID))
smallFundReturns <- data.table(sapply(allFundReturns, function(x) rep(NA, length(x))))
```

This Produces the following three tables (smallFundReturns is obviously just NA's):

```
> allFundAUM[,1:10, with = FALSE]
     33992 33261 38102 33264 33275 5606 41695 40483 41526 45993
  1:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA     1    27
  2:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA   117    NA     1    27
  3:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA   120    NA     1    27
  4:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA   133    NA     1    27
  5:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA   146    NA     1    29
 ---                                                           
260:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
261:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
262:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
263:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
264:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
> allFundReturns[,1:10, with = FALSE]
     33992 33261 38102 33264 33275 5606   41695 40483   41526   45993
  1:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA      NA    NA  0.0188 -0.0116
  2:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA -0.0315    NA -0.0120  0.0134
  3:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA -0.0978    NA -0.0908 -0.0206
  4:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA -0.0445    NA -0.0269 -0.0287
  5:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA  0.0139    NA  0.0298 -0.0141
 ---                                                                 
260:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA      NA    NA      NA      NA
261:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA      NA    NA      NA      NA
262:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA      NA    NA      NA      NA
263:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA      NA    NA      NA      NA
264:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA      NA    NA      NA      NA
> smallFundReturns[,1:10, with = FALSE]
     33992 33261 38102 33264 33275 5606 41695 40483 41526 45993
  1:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  2:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  3:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  4:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  5:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 ---                                                           
260:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
261:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
262:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
263:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
264:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA

for (i in 1:nrow(allFundReturns)){
  theSubset <- as.vector(allFundReturns[i,] <= as.numeric(quantile(allFundAUM[i,], .5, na.rm = TRUE)))
  theSubset[is.na(theSubset)] <- FALSE
  theSubset <- colnames(allFundReturns)[theSubset]
  smallFundReturns[i,theSubset, with = FALSE] = allFundReturns[i,theSubset, with = FALSE]
}
```

I am trying to subset using this for loop (using a for loop in an attempt to debug):

```
for (i in 1:nrow(allFundReturns)){
  theSubset <- as.vector(allFundReturns[i,] <= as.numeric(quantile(allFundAUM[i,], .5, na.rm = TRUE)))
  theSubset[is.na(theSubset)] <- FALSE
  theSubset <- colnames(allFundReturns)[theSubset]
  smallFundReturns[i,theSubset, with = FALSE] = allFundReturns[i,theSubset, with = FALSE]
}
```

This produces an error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, i, theSubset, with = FALSE, value = list( : 
  unused argument (with = FALSE)
```

I tried removing the 'with' part, but this spits out a bunch of warnings:

```
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, i, theSubset, value = c("41526",  ... :
  Supplied 3020 items to be assigned to 1 items of column '41526' (3019 unused)
2: In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, i, theSubset, value = c("41526",  ... :
  Supplied 3020 items to be assigned to 1 items of column '45993' (3019 unused)
3: In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, i, theSubset, value = c("41526",  ... :
  Supplied 3020 items to be assigned to 1 items of column '45994' (3019 unused)
4: In `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, i, theSubset, value = c("41526",  ... :
```

I am confused on how to do this. Any ideas on how I can subset the second data.table by the subset on the first?

EDIT:

I tried the suggestion below:

```
smallFundReturns[i,(theSubset):=allFundReturns[i,(theSubset), with = FALSE], with = FALSE]
```

And I got these warnings():

```
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(smallFundReturns, i, `:=`((theSubset),  ... :
  Coerced 'double' RHS to 'logical' to match the column's type; may have truncated precision. Either change the target column to 'double' first (by creating a new 'double' vector length 264 (nrows of entire table) and assign that; i.e. 'replace' column), or coerce RHS to 'logical' (e.g. 1L, NA_[real|integer]_, as.*, etc) to make your intent clear and for speed. Or, set the column type correctly up front when you create the table and stick to it, please.
2: In `[.data.table`(smallFundReturns, i, `:=`((theSubset),  ... :
  Coerced 'double' RHS to 'logical' to match the column's type; may have truncated precision. Either change the target column to 'double' first (by creating a new 'double' vector length 264 (nrows of entire table) and assign that; i.e. 'replace' column), or coerce RHS to 'logical' (e.g. 1L, NA_[real|integer]_, as.*, etc) to make your intent clear and for speed. Or, set the column type correctly up front when you create the table and stick to it, please.
3: In `[.data.table`(smallFundReturns, i, `:=`((theSubset),  ... :
```

And the code produced this, with 'TRUE' everywhere I would expect a number:

```
> smallFundReturns[,1:10, with = FALSE]
     33992 33261 38102 33264 33275 5606 41695 40483 41526 45993
  1:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA  TRUE  TRUE
  2:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  3:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  4:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
  5:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 ---                                                           
260:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
261:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
262:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
263:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
264:    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

EDIT 2:

I figured out the issue. Apparently, this line:

```
smallFundReturns <- data.table(sapply(allFundReturns, function(x) rep(NA, length(x))))
```

created the table as being logical. I changed it to this line:

```
smallFundReturns <- data.table(sapply(allFundReturns, function(x) as.numeric(rep(NA, length(x)))))
```

And everything worked after @HubertL fix. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write it like that:

```
smallFundReturns[i,(theSubset):=allFundReturns[i,(theSubset), with = FALSE], with = FALSE]
```

Comment: This puts 'TRUE' everywhere where i would expect the number. I very much appreciate the help, but could you walk through what that is supposed to be doing, so I can find out why 'TRUE' is showing up instead of the return I am expecting?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: pretty sure the outer `with=F` is unnecessary

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions for improvement:

Try reading data with fread instead of read.table if possible. It's way faster and the result is data.table not data.frame.

When doing "data.table operations" with the statement ", with=FALSE" you actually force R to use the much slower data.frame operations instead of using the blazingly fast data.table methods.

Have fun

Comment: Thanks! I did not know there was a read function. Also, do you know how I would achieve the same result without using with? (I'm not trying to sound rude. I am still learning the data.table package.) Or is there a better way to do this all at once, without using a loop or an apply function? To get only the 25th percentile and worse values of each column?